# How to use jquery get JSON from the backend and update innerHTML on the frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This is in my index.ejs

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ipfs-core/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script>
      async function saveFile(file) {
        const node = window.IpfsCore.create();
        return await node.files.add(file);
      }
      function receivedText() {
        document.getElementById('ipfs').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result));
      } 

      async function readfichier(e) {
        if(window.FileReader) {
          var file  = e.target.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          if (file && file.type.match('image.*')) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
          reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          }
          console.log(file);
          document.getElementById('fileNameOutput').innerHTML = document.getElementById('fileName').value;
          document.getElementById('ipfs').innerHTML = await saveFile(JSON.stringify(file));
        }
      }     
      function clickme() {
          $('file').ready(function(){ const file = $('file').prop('files')});
          var fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = select;
          document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readfichier, false);

          //fr.readAsText(file);
          //fr.readAsBinaryString(file); //as bit work with base64 for example upload to server
          
        }
        function select() {

           var id = $('file').prop('files');
           $.getJSON("/upload?" + $.param(id), function (res) {
              document.getElementById('ipfs').innerHTML = res;
            });
           
      }
    </script>
```

And this is in my index.js

```
app.get('/upload', async (req,res) => {
    const file = req.files.file;
    const fileHash = await saveFile(JSON.stringify(file));
    res.send(fileHash)
})
function success(result){
    return result
}
async function saveFile(file) {
    await ipfs.add(file, (err, result) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to upload a file and store it on the IPFS blockchain, and then load the hash of that file into the front-end.

What this should enable me to do is to load PDFs and Videos and Music and Images, and store them all on the blockchain and then implement them all onsite.

Comment: This isn't an IPFS question.

Comment: well i guess if your using IPFS you've probably done this too.